# How to update the cart quantity and price only using MVC without ajax or livewire

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, crud

This is my code in home.blade.php

```
@if (isset($cartItem))
                @foreach ($cartItem as $item)
                  <tr>
                    <td><img src="{{ 'img/' . $item->product->image }}" height="100" alt=""></td>
                    <td>{{ $item->product->name }}</td>
                    <td>Rp {{ $item->product->price }}-</td>
                    <td>
                      <form action="{{ url('/home', $item) }}">
                        @csrf 
                        @method('PATCH')
                        {{-- <input type="hidden" name="cart_id" value="{{ $item->id }}"> --}}
                        <input type="number" min="1" name="cart_quantity" value="{{ $item->quantity }}" style="background-color: #ECF2FF; padding: 5px; border: none; border-radius: 5px; width: 60px;">
                        <input type="submit" name="update_cart" value="update" class="option-btn" style="color: white; background-color: #4481eb; border: none; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px;">
                      </form>                  
                    </td>
                    <td>Rp {{ $item->product->price * $item->quantity }} /-</td>
```

The CartController

```
public function update(Request $request, Cart $cartItem)
    {
        // Validate the request
        $request->validate([
            'quantity' => 'required|integer|min:1',
            'price' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
        ]);

        // Update the cart item with the new quantity and price
        $cartItem->quantity = $request->input('quantity');
        $cartItem->product->price * $cartItem->quantity = $request->input('price');
        $cartItem->push();

        // Redirect the user back to the cart page with a success message
        return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Cart item updated successfully.');
    }
```

the route:

```
Route::patch('/home/{id}', [CartController::class, 'update']);
```

i am trying to update the cart quantity and price and the data will be also updated in database. but nothing happen when i'm changing the quantity. both quantity and price doesn't update when i click the update button and it also doesn't have any error message.

Comment: Your form need to have `method="post"` for `@method('PATCH')` to work

Comment: Add validation/error messages to your form so you can easily see if your validation fails or not. There doesn't seem to be fields named `quantity` or `price`, so validation will surely always fail

Comment: `$cartItem->product->price * $cartItem->quantity = $request->input('price');` Looks mixed up

Comment: "nothing happen - what have you tried to resolve that?